# How to write an object to gcp object store with x-goog-if-generation-match from a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'd like to write an object to gcp object store, while using the x-goog-if-generation-match feature. Using @google-cloud/storage npm library, the [file object](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File) does not seem to have an option for setting the required object generation.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the @google-cloud/storage npm library doesn't support generation and metageneration preconditions.

As an alternative, you may use either the Storage [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) or the Storage [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) which do support it. Depending on if you want to use one or the other, you'll be able to use preconditions via [HTTP Headers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_XMLAPI) or [query string parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_JSONAPI). You'll find the whole list of those [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use some kind of optimistic locking:

- get the generation id
- write object
- get the generation id again
  repeat until generation after = generation before + 1